# Setting custom CSS variable using hostbinding not working

Tags: angular

I want to set a css variable in my TS component, and set the value to an Input(). Heres what I have that isn't working:

`@HostBinding('style.--customVar') @Input() myInput = 'val';`

So I want the html to look like:

`<my-component style="--customVar:val"></my-component>`

But my host binding does not seem to trigger. I know I have the hostBinding set up properly because if I do something like:

`@HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') @Input() myInput = 'black';`

It works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems it may not be supported in angular yet. See this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9343 Luckily starting from [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9343#issuecomment-433359424) post, users came up with some workarounds

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, this solved my problem (@ Anguler 9):

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const ne = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        ne.style.setProperty('--my-offset-top', ne.offsetTop + 'px');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Came across this while looking for a solution to `@Hostbinding` problems and had notes on your problem... (seems like [Hostbinding needs some attention](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19483) from the Angular team)

Dynamically set CSS variables with `setProperty`

https://coryrylan.com/blog/theming-angular-apps-with-css-custom-properties

```
const key1 = `--theme-secondary-${color.name}`;
const value1 = color.hex;

// set variable value
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(key1, value1);
CSS.registerProperty() // create new prop
```

**An Angular specific way to access CSS**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document)

const ss = document.styleSheets[0] as CSSStyleSheet;
const rules = ss.cssRules[0] as CSSStyleRule;
console.log(rules.style.getPropertyValue('--grid-columns')); // get a prop value
```